# keyboard being skipped in while loop

Tags: java

I am making code that just creates a basket to put things in it. It is a homework assignment i have pretty much done by showing inheritance in classes and extending variables to the child classes. The simplest thing is catching me up. My while loop will only request the info from the keyboard for the fruit type on the first loop of the while, thereafter the loop skips that and moves on to how many. What am i doing wrong; keep in mind im a novice, this code may not be set up to professional level and thats ok.

```
    while((makeBasket != 'n') && (count <= 10)){

        System.out.print("What fruit would you like? ");
        fruitRequest[count] = keyboard.nextLine();

        fruitColor = getColor(fruitRequest[count]);

        System.out.print("How many " + fruitRequest[count] + " would you like? ");
        fruitCount = keyboard.nextInt();


        Fruit fruitBasket = new Fruit(fruitRequest[count], fruitColor, fruitCount);

        fruitBasket.print();
        for(int i = 0; i< 3; i++){
            switch(i){
                case 0:
                    basketRecipt[i][count] = fruitCount; 
                    break;
                case 1:
                    basketRecipt[i][count] = fruitCount * fruitBasket.getPrice(fruitRequest[count], fruitColor, fruitCount);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    basketRecipt[i][count] = fruitCount * fruitBasket.getWeight(fruitRequest[count], fruitColor, fruitCount);
                    break;
            }
            }
        count +=1;
    }
```

Comment: What is 'keyboard'. A scanner?

Comment: yes the line 'fruitRequest[count] = keyboard.nextLine();' will only ask for the fruit type once, and the additional ones up to 10 it will skip asking for input, but it will ask for "how many" from the next keyboard input .

Comment: FYI, you extend class properties/members depending on the language. The term variables is too generic for OOP. Overt_Agent is correct. The nextline function is necessary.  Good luck!

Comment: thanks for the tip, anything helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My gut instinct here is that you need to put in a `keyboard.nextLine();` after the fruitCount assignment:

```
stem.out.print("How many " + fruitRequest[count] + " would you like? ");
fruitCount = keyboard.nextInt();
keyboard.nextLine();
```

nextInt() only advances along the current line, so when the while loop runs again it does `keyboard.nextLine()` and gets an empty string of some blankspace after the int you enter.

Comment: that fixes it, explain what you mean by advancing along the current line and empty string? the string is empty before it loops the first time, and the next time it loops the string is empty because its using fruitRequest[1] essentially.

Comment: Basically, nextInt() only advances the scanner by a single integer, whilst nextLine() advances onto the next line (as you might guess). So when you use nextInt() to get the integer after fruitCount your scanner is still on the fruitCount line- just at the end of it. So when you call nextLine() on the 2nd run of the loop it's just returning an empty "" String- as that's all that's left on the line. I hope this clears things up, if not I suggest asking your teacher, they can probably explain it better than I can.